# Image.FromStream throws ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, image, stream

I'm trying to output an image to the output stream through an HttpHandler but it keeps throwing an ArgumentException. I've googled the issue and tried so many things but I still couldn't fix the problem. Anyway, here's the code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 imageId = context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null ? 
            Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]) : default(Int32);

        if (imageId != 0)
        {
            //context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Byte[] imageData = this._imageInfoManager.GetTradeMarkImage(imageId);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length))
            {
                using (Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true)) //this line throws
                {
                    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Image could not be found.");
    }
```

Note that the imageData byte array is not empty and the memory stream is being filled up correctly. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** 
Here's the code for `GetTradeMarkImage`... Note that the images are stored in the an SQL Server database in the `image` format.

```
    public Byte[] GetTradeMarkImage(Int32 id)
    {
        object result = DB.ExecuteScalar(SqlConstants.SqlProcedures.Request_GetImageById, id);

        if (result != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(ms, result);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }                
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The byte array may well not be empty, but that's not the same as it being *correct*. What does the code for `GetTradeMarkImage` look like, and what format is the image data in?

Comment: This exception also comes when stream does not have a valid image format.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I updated the question and included the code that gets the image from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now you've posted the `GetTradeMarkImage` code, that's almost certainly the problem:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, result);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Why would you expect the value of `BinaryFormatter` to be a valid image stream? It's not clear what's in your database (a BLOB?) nor what the execution-time type of `result` is here (which you should find out by debugging) but you *shouldn't* be using `BinaryFormatter` here. I suspect you *just* want to get the raw data out of the database, and put that into the byte array.

If you're lucky, you *may* just be able to cast `result` to `byte[]` to start with. (I don't know what `ExecuteScalar` does with blobs, and this obviously isn't the "normal" `ExecuteScalar` method anyway). Otherwise, you may need to use an alternative approach, opening a `DataReader` and getting the value that way.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes actually I just want the raw data from the database and then I want to show the image on the screen. The data is stored as `image` inside the DB.

Comment: casting byte[] did not work. ExecuteScalar is just a wrapper around the corresponding method in the Enterprise Library. But aside from that, do you think I should be storing the data in some other field type?

Comment: @Kassem: Well I did say to find out the execution-time type of `result` by debugging... What *is* the execution-time type? It's fine to use an `image` type in the database, but you'll need different code to get the data out. Without knowing the type of the value of `result`, it's hard to say exactly what.

Comment: The execution-time type of `result` is `byte[]`.

Comment: @Kassem: Then you should be able to cast it to `byte[]`. You said that didn't work... so what happened?

Comment: @Kassem: Then perhaps your data is invalid in the database? Try saving it to a file directly, and see whether it loads correctly in Explorer...

Comment: Ok I ended up not using the binary formatter altogether and that actually worked. But I still needed to wrap the `byte[]` inside the `MemoryStream` and then return it as `ms.ToArray()`. I previously tried returning the data straight from the DB but it did not work. Do you have an explanation why I need to wrap it with the `MemoryStream`?

Comment: @Kassem: No, you don't need to create a `MemoryStream` and call `ToArray`. Just return the cast `byte[]` - that should be fine.